# How to calculate the broadcast year and month out of the given date?

Tags: sql, calendar, spreadsheet

Is there a way to calculate the the broadcast year and month for a given gregorian date?

The advertising broadcast calendar differs from the regular calendar, in the way that every month needs to start on a Monday and end on a Sunday and have exactly 4 or 5 weeks. You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_calendar

This is a pretty common thing in TV advertising, so I guess there is a standard mathematical formula for it, that uses a combination of date functions (week(), month(), etc...).

Here is an example mapping between gregorian and broadcast dates:

```
| gregorian_date | broadcast_month | broadcast_year |
+----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|   2014-12-27   |       12        |     2014       |
|   2014-12-28   |       12        |     2014       |
|   2014-12-29   |        1        |     2015       |
|   2014-12-30   |        1        |     2015       |
|   2014-12-31   |        1        |     2015       |
|   2015-01-01   |        1        |     2015       |
|   2015-01-02   |        1        |     2015       |
```

Here is example how the broadcast calendar looks for 2015:
http://www.rab.com/public/reports/BroadcastCalendar_2015.pdf

Comment: What output do you want, or is the table you gave in the above OP the output?

Comment: I am trying to construct a function / formula that will take the Gregorian date as an input, and will output the broadcast year and month. I such a function exists, as this is a pretty common thing in advertising.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the pattern is that the first of the Gregorian month always falls within the first week of the Broadcast calendar, and any days from the previous month are pulled forward into that month to create full weeks. In Excel, you can use the following formula in cell B2 (first of your broadcast months above) to calculate the broadcast month:

```
=MONTH(A2+(7-WEEKDAY(A2,2)))
```

Similarly, in cell C2:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=12,B2=1),YEAR(A2)+1,YEAR(A2))
```

This will return the broadcast month and year for any dates you put into your data set.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I did some initial testing, and this seems to be working great for me in a similar use case!

Answer (score 0):

```
month,first,last
2018_1,2018-01-01,2018-01-28
2018_2,2018-01-29,2018-02-25
2018_3,2018-02-26,2018-03-25
2018_4,2018-03-26,2018-04-29
2018_5,2018-04-30,2018-05-27
2018_6,2018-05-28,2018-06-24
2018_7,2018-06-25,2018-07-29
2018_8,2018-07-30,2018-08-26
2018_9,2018-08-27,2018-09-30
2018_10,2018-10-01,2018-10-28
2018_11,2018-10-29,2018-11-25
2018_12,2018-11-26,2018-12-30
2019_1,2018-12-31,2019-01-27
2019_2,2019-01-28,2019-02-24
2019_3,2019-02-25,2019-03-31
2019_4,2019-04-01,2019-04-28
2019_5,2019-04-29,2019-05-26
2019_6,2019-05-27,2019-06-30
2019_7,2019-07-01,2019-07-28
2019_8,2019-07-29,2019-08-25
2019_9,2019-08-26,2019-09-29
2019_10,2019-09-30,2019-10-27
2019_11,2019-10-28,2019-11-24
2019_12,2019-11-25,2019-12-29
2020_1,2019-12-30,2020-01-26
2020_2,2020-01-27,2020-02-23
2020_3,2020-02-24,2020-03-29
2020_4,2020-03-30,2020-04-26
2020_5,2020-04-27,2020-05-31
2020_6,2020-06-01,2020-06-28
2020_7,2020-06-29,2020-07-26
2020_8,2020-07-27,2020-08-30
2020_9,2020-08-31,2020-09-27
2020_10,2020-09-28,2020-10-25
2020_11,2020-10-26,2020-11-29
2020_12,2020-11-30,2020-12-27
2021_1,2020-12-28,2021-01-31
2021_2,2021-02-01,2021-02-28
2021_3,2021-03-01,2021-03-28
2021_4,2021-03-29,2021-04-25
2021_5,2021-04-26,2021-05-30
2021_6,2021-05-31,2021-06-27
2021_7,2021-06-28,2021-07-25
2021_8,2021-07-26,2021-08-29
2021_9,2021-08-30,2021-09-26
2021_10,2021-09-27,2021-10-31
2021_11,2021-11-01,2021-11-28
2021_12,2021-11-29,2021-12-26
2022_1,2021-12-27,2022-01-30
2022_2,2022-01-31,2022-02-27
2022_3,2022-02-28,2022-03-27
2022_4,2022-03-28,2022-04-24
2022_5,2022-04-25,2022-05-29
2022_6,2022-05-30,2022-06-26
2022_7,2022-06-27,2022-07-31
2022_8,2022-08-01,2022-08-28
2022_9,2022-08-29,2022-09-25
2022_10,2022-09-26,2022-10-30
2022_11,2022-10-31,2022-11-27
2022_12,2022-11-28,2022-12-25
2023_1,2022-12-26,2023-01-29
2023_2,2023-01-30,2023-02-26
2023_3,2023-02-27,2023-03-26
2023_4,2023-03-27,2023-04-30
2023_5,2023-05-01,2023-05-28
2023_6,2023-05-29,2023-06-25
2023_7,2023-06-26,2023-07-30
2023_8,2023-07-31,2023-08-27
2023_9,2023-08-28,2023-09-24
2023_10,2023-09-25,2023-10-29
2023_11,2023-10-30,2023-11-26
2023_12,2023-11-27,2023-12-31
2024_1,2024-01-01,2024-01-28
2024_2,2024-01-29,2024-02-25
2024_3,2024-02-26,2024-03-31
2024_4,2024-04-01,2024-04-28
2024_5,2024-04-29,2024-05-26
2024_6,2024-05-27,2024-06-30
2024_7,2024-07-01,2024-07-28
2024_8,2024-07-29,2024-08-25
2024_9,2024-08-26,2024-09-29
2024_10,2024-09-30,2024-10-27
2024_11,2024-10-28,2024-11-24
2024_12,2024-11-25,2024-12-29
2025_1,2024-12-30,2025-01-26
2025_2,2025-01-27,2025-02-23
2025_3,2025-02-24,2025-03-30
2025_4,2025-03-31,2025-04-27
2025_5,2025-04-28,2025-05-25
2025_6,2025-05-26,2025-06-29
2025_7,2025-06-30,2025-07-27
2025_8,2025-07-28,2025-08-31
2025_9,2025-09-01,2025-09-28
2025_10,2025-09-29,2025-10-26
2025_11,2025-10-27,2025-11-30
2025_12,2025-12-01,2025-12-28
```

Comment: how did you generate this list?